# Layout Became Unresponsive while click on navigation drawer normal and expandable ListView

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

This is my main activity file which contains the drawer layout.

```
public abstract class ParentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NetworkStateReceiverListener {
    private final String TAG = ParentActivity.this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    protected ListView mDrawerList;


    protected static int position;

    private static boolean isLaunch = true;


    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;



    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private boolean mSlideState;
    private MenuItem drawer_btn;
    private RelativeLayout subItem1;
    private RelativeLayout subItem2;
    private RelativeLayout subItem3;
    public NetworkStateReceiver networkStateReceiver = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer_base_layout);
        Utils.registerNetworkStateReceiver(this, networkStateReceiver, this);
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        drawer_btn = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer_button);
        NavigationAdapter adapter = new NavigationAdapter(this);





        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                openActivity(position);
            }
        });

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                       
                mDrawerLayout,              
                R.drawable.ic_launcher,     
                R.string.open_drawer,     
                R.string.close_drawer)    
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                mSlideState = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                mSlideState = true;
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
                super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);



        if (isLaunch) {

            isLaunch = false;
            openActivity(0);
        }
    }


    protected void openActivity(int position) {


        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        ParentActivity.position = position; //Setting currently selected position in this field so that it will be available in our child activities.

        switch (position) {
            case 0:

                break;
            case 1: {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, HotelListScreen.class);
                Utils.startActivityClearTop(this, intent);
            }
            break;

            case 2: {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallUsScreen.class);
                Utils.startActivityClearTop(this, intent);
            }
            break;
            case 3:

                break;
            case 4:

                break;
            case 5:

                break;
            case 6:

                break;
            case 8: {
                if (ApplicationDataLayer.getInstance().getSelectedHotel() != null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BankDetails.class);
                    Utils.startActivityClearTop(this, intent);
                } else {
                    dialog = MultipleDialogs.createDialogOneBtnWithoutTitle(this, this.getResources().getString(R.string.pls_select_hotel), new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                }

            }
            break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Item Position::" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    private Dialog dialog;

    private ActionBar actionBar = null;

    public void setUpActionBar() {
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.show();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.title_bg));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_drawer_button) {
            if (mSlideState) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
        return false;

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (null != networkStateReceiver && null != this) {
            Utils.removeNetworkStateReceiverListener(this, networkStateReceiver, this);
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

NavigationAdapter.java

```
public class NavigationAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity mActivity;
private ArrayList<DrawerHolderPOJO> mDrawerOptions = new ArrayList<DrawerHolderPOJO>();
private ImageView arrow;
private RelativeLayout subItem1;
private RelativeLayout subItem2;
private RelativeLayout subItem3;
private boolean isHelpOpen = false;

public NavigationAdapter(Activity activity) {
    this.mActivity = activity;

    String[] title = activity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_options_string);
    String[] subTitleHelp = activity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_options_help_string);

    TypedArray ar = activity.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.drawer_options_img);
    int len = ar.length();
    int[] image = new int[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        image[i] = ar.getResourceId(i, 0);
    }
    ar.recycle();

    int noSubcontentLayout = 0;
    boolean subcontentPresent = false;
    mDrawerOptions.add(new DrawerHolderPOJO(title[0], noSubcontentLayout, image[0], subcontentPresent));
    mDrawerOptions.add(new DrawerHolderPOJO(title[1], noSubcontentLayout, image[1], subcontentPresent));
    if (!(activity instanceof HotelListScreen || activity instanceof HotelDetailScreen)) {
        mDrawerOptions.add(new DrawerHolderPOJO(title[2], noSubcontentLayout, image[2], subcontentPresent));
        mDrawerOptions.add(new DrawerHolderPOJO(title[3], noSubcontentLayout, image[3], subcontentPresent));
        mDrawerOptions.add(new DrawerHolderPOJO(title[4], noSubcontentLayout, image[4], subcontentPresent));
        mDrawerOptions.add(new DrawerHolderPOJO(title[5], noSubcontentLayout, image[5], subcontentPresent));
        mDrawerOptions.add(new DrawerHolderPOJO(title[6], noSubcontentLayout, image[6], subcontentPresent));
        mDrawerOptions.add(new DrawerHolderPOJO(title[7], noSubcontentLayout, image[7], subcontentPresent));
        mDrawerOptions.add(new DrawerHolderPOJO(title[8], noSubcontentLayout, image[8], subcontentPresent));
    }
    mDrawerOptions.add(new DrawerHolderPOJO(title[9], noSubcontentLayout, image[9], subcontentPresent));

    //HELP TODO Need to give noSubcontentLayout
    mDrawerOptions.add(new DrawerHolderPOJO(title[10], R.layout.drawer_list_sub_item, image[10], true));
    mDrawerOptions.add(new DrawerHolderPOJO(title[11], noSubcontentLayout, image[11], subcontentPresent));
    mDrawerOptions.add(new DrawerHolderPOJO(title[12], noSubcontentLayout, image[12], subcontentPresent));


}


private class ViewHolder {
    TextView optionName;
    ImageView imageOption;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
            mActivity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.optionName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_name);
        holder.imageOption = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_img);
        arrow = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrow);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    DrawerHolderPOJO rowItem = (DrawerHolderPOJO) getItem(position);

    holder.optionName.setText(rowItem.getItemName());
    holder.imageOption.setImageResource(rowItem.getItemImage());

    if (rowItem.isSubcontent()) {
        arrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        arrow.setTag(convertView);
        arrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View cView = (View) v.getTag();
                subItem1 = (RelativeLayout) cView.findViewById(R.id.sub_item1);
                subItem2 = (RelativeLayout) cView.findViewById(R.id.sub_item2);
                subItem3 = (RelativeLayout) cView.findViewById(R.id.sub_item3);
                arrow = (ImageView) cView.findViewById(R.id.arrow);
                TextView subText1 = (TextView) subItem1.findViewById(R.id.option_name);
                TextView subText2 = (TextView) subItem2.findViewById(R.id.option_name);
                TextView subText3 = (TextView) subItem3.findViewById(R.id.option_name);
                if (!isHelpOpen) {
                    isHelpOpen = true;

                    arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.up_arrow_white);


                    subText1.setText("Tutorial Video");
                    subText2.setText("FAQs");
                    subText3.setText("Feedback");
                    subItem1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    subItem2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    subItem3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    isHelpOpen = false;
                    arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_arrow_white);
                    subItem1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    subItem2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    subItem3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });


    }
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mDrawerOptions.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mDrawerOptions.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return mDrawerOptions.indexOf(getItem(position));
}
```

}

drawer_list_item.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/list_item"
     android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:padding="@dimen/hotel_detail_item_padding"
       >
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/option_img"
      android:layout_width="39dp"
      android:layout_height="39dp"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/hotel_detail_item_margin_top_bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/hotel_detail_item_margin_top_bottom"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/hotel_detail_item_margin_left_right"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/arrow"
    android:layout_width="39dp"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/down_arrow_white"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/hotel_detail_image_item_margin_left_right"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/option_name"
    style="@style/TextFontStyleNavigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/arrow"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/option_img"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
      <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
       android:background="#b3b3b3">
      <include
      android:id="@+id/sub_item1"
      layout="@layout/drawer_list_sub_item"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
     <include
      android:id="@+id/sub_item2"
      layout="@layout/drawer_list_sub_item"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
     <include
      android:id="@+id/sub_item3"
      layout="@layout/drawer_list_sub_item"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
    </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

----------------------Sub Layouts--------------------

```
    <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/hotel_detail_item_padding"
android:visibility="gone">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/option_name"
    style="@style/TextFontStyleNavigationSubItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_left_drawer_sub_item"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Large Text" />
```

Now I am not able to click anywhere on the screen when the navigation drawer is opened or clicked or closed. The main content other than the drawer freezes and does not recognize any click.

Comment: Are you sure your subItem1,2 and three have the relative layout as xmls? because there is no any sub layout which you include is not posted in your question

Comment: and one thing i suggest you to use the expandable list and BaseExpandableListAdapter instead simple listview and baseadapter if you have to manage sublist expand and collapse

Comment: yes I have the relative layout for sub Item1, 2 and 3. Morover, I have tried it usind expandable listview but the issue was still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working fine ...Please check your other related code.

Checked in demo code. :)

Thanks for good example.

Comment: Sorry, I found the problem. It was in some other code.